# How to avoid ImportError when using python on Macos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy, kivymd

I have tried using the following script:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MDLabel(text="Hello, World", halign="center")


MainApp().run()
```

I get the following error:
[image: Error]
I am using Python 3.8.9!

Comment: A [PR with `SmoothRectangle`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/8309) was merged just two weeks ago. It was not yet released to PyPI. You can try to install [`kivy`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy) from GitHub.

Comment: Post text as text here, not images.